# MATLAB script gives me NaN even for setting variables to integers

Tags: matlab, optimization

After running this script everything is set to NaN and nothing happens. I'm just trying to do a secant method on a 2-d function where one variable is set to 0.

```
hi = @(x,y) exp(-3*((x + 0.5).^2 + 2*y.^2)) + exp(-x.^2 - 2*y.^2).*cos(4*x) - 1e-3;

tol = 1e-10;

yi = 0;

x0 = -2; x1 = 2;
f0 = hi(x0,yi); f1 = hi(x1,yi);

    for jj = 1:24
        x2 = x1 - f1*(x1-x0)/(f1-f0);
        f2 = hi(x2,yi);

    if (abs(x2-x1) < tol)
        root = x2;
        break
    else
        x0 = x1; x1 = x2;
        f0 = f1; f1 = f2;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here. The first is in this line:

```
x2 = x1 - f1*(x1-x0)/(f1-f0);
```

The denominator `f1-f0` will cause `x2` to blow up when the function becomes flat. You can avoid this either by stopping when `abs(f1-f0) < tol`, or by adding `tol` to the denominator:

```
x2 = x1 - f1*(x1-x0)/(f1-f0+tol);
```

However, this won't find the root you want. Graphing your function reveals the problem:

[image]

You start the search at `x0=-2` and `x1=+2`, which are two values that bound three roots, but the search will start with `x2=-10.5203`, and will proceed to try and find the root that lies at negative infinity. If you choose better starting values, you can find any of the three roots using your original code. For example:

```
  x0      x1       root
------  ------    ------
 -1.0    +1.0      1.9522
 -0.5    +0.5      0.4164
 +0.6    +1.0      1.1789
```

When finding roots (or minimizing/maximizing functions), the starting point of the search often makes a difference. It's best to double check your starting points and to know as much about the function you're working with as you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
f1*(x1-x0)/(f1-f0)
```

At some moment `f1 = f0` and this gives you `Inf`

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine from a quick look over, but as @sfstewman points out, you start your search over a range that includes a maximum and a minimum in the function, leading to divergent behavior.

Try starting the search with a different range e.g.

```
x0 = 0; x1 = 2;
```

and it will converge.

Comment: Hey, @TryHard! It's been long :-) Welcome back to answering Matlab!

Comment: Thanks @LuisMendo - it's been a while ;)